# How to implement mixed authentication using Spring Security providing single sign-on with WAFFLE and form based authentication?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, waffle

In my Spring Boot based web application there should be two authentication options. On the one hand, single sign-on should be used, which is the default way. On the other hand, a form-based authentication should also be offered. This is commonly known as Mixed Authentication.

If the form-based authentication is used, server-side known user accounts are checked.  Single sign-on uses the Windows logon.

I could already successfully integrate WAFFLE as a single sign-on component into the server application and used the example of [mgoldgeier](https://github.com/mgoldgeier/waffle-spring-boot-demo) as a template.

There are examples of Mixed Authentication with WAFFLE related to Tomcat ([here](https://code.dblock.org/2010/05/27/tomcat-single-sign-on-mixed-with-form-authentication-w-waffle.html) and [here](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/blob/master/Docs/tomcat/TomcatMixedSingleSignOnAndFormAuthenticatorValve.md)), but unfortunately I couldn't find any code related to Spring Boot or Spring Security.

I'd love it if someone could give me an example!

Comment: Perhaps an approach: https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/issues/460#issuecomment-433377214

Comment: Another approach: https://groups.google.com/g/waffle-users/c/nKYO6fw8eIU/m/lI2ttX7FAgAJ